# How to move a gameobject using movetowards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I make my `GameObject` move towards another `GameObject` using `Vector3.MoveTowards` method?

Heres my current code:

```
void update()
{
    TargetObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (TargetObject.transform.position, Cube.transform.position , MaxDistanceDelta);
}
```

Comment: Third parameter ( the one you've named `MaxDistanceDelta` ) distinguish how long the delta between previous and the new position can be. If that delta is lower than the third parameter then the target position will be equal to the cube position. The code you've posted should work perfectly fine and the only thing that can be wrong in here is that third parameter.

Comment: IDK if that's the wrong copy/paste but the method should be called `Update()` and not `update()` confirm that with your real source.

Comment: oh, thks for the explanation on maxDistanceDelta and as for void update, i did not copy and paste from source code and i kinda forgotten to put the first letter to cap.

Answer (score 4):

```
void Update() { 
    myGameObject.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(myGameObject.transform.position, targetObject.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

- myGameObject - object you want to move
- targetObject - object you are moving to
- speed - float value to set the speed

Comment: hi, is it possible to make the myGameObject's y axis not to follow the targetObject?

Comment: Just change the the return value of `Vector3.MoveTowards`.  

`Vector3 pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(myGameObject.transform.position, targetObject.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
pos.y = 0;
myGameObject.transform.position = pos;`

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see the details and parameters of the method:

```
MoveTowards(Vector3 current, Vector3 target, float maxDistanceDelta);
```

### Understanding the parameters

- **Vector3 current:** 3D vector of the object position (example: `new Vector(0,0,1)`)
- **Vector3 target:** 3D vector of the target position (example: `new Vector(3,4,5)`)
- **maxDistanceDelta:** maximum distance that the object will move when the method is called. (Example: if `maxDistanceDelta` is 1, the object will move 1 unit every time it's called. In case we are not using `Time.deltaTime` it would move 50 units a second if the frame rate is 50)

**Note:** If the actual distance remaining is less than `maxDistanceDelta`, it will be placed on target position. Meaning the object will  no longer move unless the target position changes.

### Example:

Declaring the variables:

```
public float speed;
public Transform target;
```

Using the method:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
      transform.position, 
      target.position, 
      speed * Time.deltaTime 
);
```